# How do you iterate over an array to create a hash?

Tags: ruby

I need to create a hash from the array below, and have it look like - peoples_ages = {"Joe"=> 25}. I can iterate over it using each_with_index, but I don't need the index as the value, I need the person's age. Instead I was thinking of using either Hash[people_array]... or .each_with_object. Is it best to use .map instead and just put .to_h after?

```
class Person

attr_reader :name, :age

def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
end
end

nick = Person.new("Nick", 25)
jim = Person.new("Jim", 37)
bob = Person.new("Bob", 23)
rob = Person.new("Rob", 29)
sue = Person.new("Sue", 31)

peeps = [nick, jim, bob, rob, sue]

# iterate over peeps array to create a hash that looks like this:
# people_ages = {
#   "Nick" => 25,
#   "Jim" => 37,
#   "Bob" => 23,
# etc...
# }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Hash[peeps.map {|person| [person.name, person.age]} ]
```

Or if Ruby 2.0

```
peeps.map {|person| [person.name, person.age]}.to_h
```

Answer (score 4):

```
peeps.each_with_object({}){|e, h| h[e.name] = e.age}
```